# Reformatting a data set using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

So I've never used XSLT before, so this is probably a very simple problem.  Basically, my job is to chapter videos, and the program we use generates an XML document containing pairs of timecodes (where the chapter starts, in milliseconds) and a title (the name of the chapter).  What I want to do is rearrange it into a format that Final Cut Pro understands.

The program generates data in the following format:

```
<marker time="27">
<label>Introduction</label>
</marker>
```

and Final Cut needs it in this format (with the timecode converted into frames, aka divided by 33.3):

```
<marker>
    <name>Introduction</name>
    <comment> &lt;CHAPTER>
    </comment>
    <color>
        <alpha>0</alpha>
        <red>127</red>
        <green>0</green>
        <blue>255</blue>
    </color>
    <in>27</in>
    <out>-1</out>
</marker>
```

The code I've written is:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:for-each select="captionate/markers/marker">
<marker>
    <name><xsl:value-of select="label"/></name>
    <comment> &lt;CHAPTER>
    </comment>
    <color>
        <alpha>0</alpha>
        <red>127</red>
        <green>0</green>
        <blue>255</blue>
    </color>
    <in><xsl:value-of select="@time"/></in>
    <out>-1</out>
</marker>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

but it's not working (I'm not even entirely sure how to implement it).  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @Adam: what is not working? I tried your code and it seems to produce almost exactly the output you gave as an example above. Almost, because instead of `CHAPTER>` it produces `CHAPTER&gt;`. Is that your problem? Or do you hassle with the division by 33.3? Or what else?

Comment: Can't see anything wrong in the snippets, are your namespaces, if any correct? Have you tried `//markers/marker` ?

Comment: @Doc Brown: Really?  I guess maybe I just don't know how to implement it then.  I just added the line <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="captionate_fcp.xsl"?> to the code I wanted to transform and opened it in Firefox.  What came out was all the text with none of the tags.  Is there some other way to apply the changes?  Also, I'm having trouble with the whole dividing by 33 thing required to convert from milliseconds to frames.  Is there a way to do mathematical operations in XSLT?  Thanks so much for your quick response!

Comment: `&lt;CHAPTER>` you should write `&lt;CHAPTER&gt;` otherwise the xml will result non well formed. Is it a typo? Or it's the cause of your problems?

Comment: You should better use an XSLT processor like Saxon.

Comment: @empo: `&lt;CHAPTER>` *is* well formed.

Comment: @empo: not true. `>` does not have to be escaped in XML (except in rare situations involving CDATA sections).

Comment: @empo God, I'm an idiot.  I didn't realize you needed a separate XSLT processor.  I downloaded one, and it worked like a charm!  Thank you all so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have completed your sample data (perhaps it now matches yours exactly?):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<captionate>
<markers>
<marker time="27">
<label>Introduction</label>
</marker>
</markers>
</captionate>
```

Here is the code again, only minimal changes (shows the division):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:for-each select="captionate/markers/marker">
<marker>
    <name><xsl:value-of select="label"/></name>
    <comment> &lt;CHAPTER&gt;
    </comment>
    <color>
        <alpha>0</alpha>
        <red>127</red>
        <green>0</green>
        <blue>255</blue>
    </color>
    <in><xsl:value-of select="@time div 33.33"/></in>
    <out>-1</out>
</marker>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Running this through xsltproc gives the expected results.